# Is it possible to show when an executable was run for the last time?

Tags: executable

Note that the FS is mounted with the *relatime* option (thus the recent last access time is not shown).

Is there a way to see when an executable (ELF 64-bit LSB executable) was run for the last time?

Using root access. The idea is that a complex production application can run the same exec that currently exists at two different places (pending installation). I just want to ensure that only one of them is run from now on, without interrupting anything (cannot temporarily remove one for instance ; it's 99% sure only one of them is used, but need to be 100% sure).

Comment: Do you have audit logging enabled?

Comment: It's not enabled (for performance reason).

Comment: How about process accounting (`acct`)?

Comment: @StephenKitt Great idea, it's not installed yet, but can do it. Does it have a performance impact? (monitoring only 2 execs)

Comment: If audit logging or process accounting has a performance impact _that actually matters to you_ is not something that anyone could tell you. We don't even know whether a millisecond, minute or day of extra time to your unknown workflow matters to you or whether your system is heavily I/O limited or all running in a VM in RAM. Also, don't you have a development or testing setup that you could test things on, or do you require us to give you zero-error professional suggestions for your unknown production system?

Comment: Doesn't `relatime` update the access time every 24 h or if the old atime was earlier than mtime? That would let you know if the program has been unused for a full day, or you could just `touch programfile` and then check if the atime gets updated after that. That is of course assuming there's nothing else to read the file.

Comment: @ilkkachu That is correct and relevant. But the changes were done a couple hours ago, and we don't want to wait for a whole day.

Comment: @Déjàvu, hence the thing about `touch`ing the file to update mtime. running the program should update atime if it was <= mtime.

Comment: Or you could always just `chmod a-x` and check for errors :P

Comment: @ilkkachu That is the solution, smart, with no performance impact risk on the system (touch and check access time). Please detail this in the answer section, I'll accept it.

Comment: @they The specifications given are not really detailed, and a general comment like "we usually notice an impact on the load" could have been mentioned (or nothing), based on this simple problem description. We did actually install it on a test server (acct is great) and did not notice any impact, but someone who used it - as it seems it is the case of Stephen Kitt - could still have an interesting input about that, and this is why the comment was addressed to him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I recall, `relatime` updates the access time every 24 h or if the old atime was earlier than or equal to mtime. That would let you know if the program has been unused for a full day; or, if you don't care to wait, run `touch programfile` and then see if the atime has changed later.

Plain `touch` would set atime == mtime, but atime gets updated if it's <= mtime, so that's ok. You could also do something like `touch -a -d 1999-12-31` instead to change atime without modifying mtime.

Like so:

```
$ cp /bin/ls .
$ touch ./ls
$ stat ./ls
...
Access: 2022-01-07 13:07:16.640132600 +0200
Modify: 2022-01-07 13:07:16.640132600 +0200
Change: 2022-01-07 13:07:16.640132600 +0200
 Birth: -
$ ./ls > /dev/null
$ stat ./ls
...
Access: 2022-01-07 13:07:57.175525517 +0200
Modify: 2022-01-07 13:07:16.640132600 +0200
Change: 2022-01-07 13:07:16.640132600 +0200
 Birth: -
```

The access timestamp was updated when the program was run.

Of course, atime would also change if the file is just *read*. It's probably not that common for binary files to be read just like that, but e.g. a backup tool could do just that. That would make atime useless for this.

But if atime doesn't change, then the file has been neither read nor executed, so it can be used to prove the negative case.

Comment: With the caveat that the most recent _access_ time could have been a plain read, rather than execution.  I think you need a system with process accounting enabled to know when particular programs were run...

Comment: @TobySpeight, yes, that's true. It still works to prove the negative though, and that just might be enough. At least as long as there isn't e.g. a backup tool running that unconditionally reads everything regurlarly...

Comment: I'm not that familiar with accounting so I won't be the one to write that answer...

Answer (score 2):

You might be in a position to modify the program to make it log when it is used.

Move the program to a new location (e.g. `/usr/bin/program.real`) and replace it with a short wrapper script that writes the time to a file:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/date -u >/var/log/program.access
exec /usr/bin/program.real "$@"
```

Obviously, you can add a `+` argument to format the date string as you would like.